# List of all rendered words' boxes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, render, paragraph, custom-painting

How can I have list of boxes containing all **words** I render, I need it to determine which **word** is user long clicking?
In other words how can I find what **maxRange** so I can use **getBoxesForRange**  in code below?

My code :

```
var pin = Offset(0, 0);
    // To create a paragraph of text, we use ParagraphBuilder.
    final ui.ParagraphBuilder builder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(
      ui.ParagraphStyle(
        textDirection: ui.TextDirection.rtl,
        textAlign: ebookTextAlign,
        fontFamily: "Asan",
        fontSize: ebookMainTextSize,
      ),
    )..pushStyle(ui.TextStyle(color: const ui.Color(0xFF000000)));

    spans.forEach((spn) {
      if (spn.localName == "p") builder.addText("\n");
      builder.addText(spn.text + " ");
    });
    builder.pop();

    paragraph = builder.build()
      ..layout(ui.ParagraphConstraints(width: size.width));

    var list = new List<ExtendedTextBox>();
    var boxes = paragraph.getBoxesForRange(0, maxRange);
```

Comment: `"I need it to determine which word is user long clicking"` - use `getPositionForOffset()` + `getWordBoundary()`

Comment: great! now I have boundary, how can I find the actual paragraph string of this boundary?

Comment: `String.sunbstring()` ?

Comment: I mean how can I have "text of paragraph", there is no paragraph.text
I create paragraph by calling lots of Paragraph.addText(...), shall I combine all spans and use boundary to substring it or there is a better way?

Comment: kind of - you call `addText` so you know what text you are adding to your paragraph - i dont see any `combinedText` property in the `Paragraph`

Comment: Please post your comments above as an answer, it was useful and worked.

Comment: write a self answer then...